# Draw bean machine

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, mat

I'm trying to draw [Bean Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_machine) as follow:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
    int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;

    g.drawLine(xCenter + 20, yCenter, xCenter + 20, yCenter + 20); // right horizontal line
    g.drawLine(xCenter, yCenter, xCenter, yCenter + 20); //left horizontal line
    g.drawLine(xCenter + 20, yCenter + 20, xCenter + 70, yCenter + 110); // right line
    g.drawLine(xCenter, yCenter + 20, xCenter - 50, yCenter + 110); //left line
    g.drawLine(xCenter - 50, yCenter + 110, xCenter + 70, yCenter + 110);//base line

    //draw nails
    for (int i = 1; i <= nails; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            g.fillOval(xCenter  + i, yCenter + 20 * j, (int)(0.09 * xCenter) / 3, (int)(0.09 * yCenter) / 3);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm facing issue with drawing ovals (Ovals represent nails as know), I dun know how to do it correctly,

Here is what I get.

[image]

The expected output is know for all I though.

Comment: Why down vote :/

Comment: What is the resulting value of `(int) (0.09 * xCenter) / 3`?

Comment: @d.j.brown It's represent the height and width for nail (oval shape) and I think no problem with it.

Comment: @user1058652 you are right, but since I do not know what the specific output should be it is difficult to help. It seems like the spacing between your 'nails' is not correct, which you should account for.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here:

- `fillOval(xCenter  + i` needs to be `fillOval(xCenter + 20 * i`. This explains why every row gets a little longer than the other, because your nails are squished together and overlap each other.
- Right now, you have more nails on top. If you let the outer loop count backwards, you can turn the pyramid around.
- Your nails look like squares because they are too small to have rounded corners.

When fixing the x coordinate of `fillOval` and making th dots larger (0.29 instead of 0.09), it looks like this:

[image]